# how to override plot.default in own R package?

Tags: r

So I'm making an R package. In this package, I have a function `foo1` that returns an `S3` list whose component can be ploted. Right now I have a function `plotfoo1` which does that. E.g. the following currently works:

```
output1<-foo1(Data)
plotfoo1(output1)
```

Now my question. I want to override the plot function in R such that the following would yield the same output:

```
plot(output1)
```

but I don't know how to do that. I'm looking for (a link?) explaining how to do that. It should be possible as it seems that many packages have thei own custom plot function...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to overwrite `plot.default` - that would be a terrible idea.  What you probably should do instead is make it so that `foo1` returns an object with a class that you create and write a S3 plot method for that class type.  Here is an an example

```
foo1 <- function(){
  dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10))
  # Give the data a class
  class(dat) <- "myclass"
  return(dat)
}

# Write plot function for objects that
# have class "myclass"
plot.myclass <- function(obj, ...){
  plot.default(obj$x, obj$y)
}

mydata <- foo1()
# See - it has class "myclass"
class(mydata)
# plot recognizes that mydata has class "myclass"
# and calls plot.myclass on mydata automatically
plot(mydata)
```

Comment: Very nice -- tho' as a Grumpy Old Man I should give you `-1` for using a `1` where it could be easily misread as **fool** rather than "foo-one"  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Well my whole aim in answering this question was to call you a fool so that -1 would be well deserved.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I [pity the foo1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJnKm6ftPu0) who makes a mistake like that.